# Equal width of the first column between multiple composites

Tags: java, swt

So the case is that I have a SWT composite A which aggregates composite B and C.
The content of B and C consists of multiple rows that consists of Label and Text.
Within composite B or C rows are aligned properly ( you can draw a straight vertical line in the place where label border ends and text starts). But if you compare B and C then C content looks like it is indented against B.

For example:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve it ?

Comment: Why not use a `GridLayout` for B and C together? Do they have to be separate?

Comment: There is a mechanism that shows B or C or D or E ( and many others ) depending on the configuration. If I don't have separate composites I would have to iterate over multiple widgets and set their visibility separately which is something I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of to align the first column of each `Composite` is to set the `GridData#widthHint` to the same value. This value would have to be the maximal width of any of the elements in the first column.

I gave it a try and came up with this solution (it's not optimized and consequently might not be the most efficient way to do it):

```
private static Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Composite first = createComposite(shell);
    Composite second = createComposite(shell);

    synchronizeFirstColumn(2, first, second);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static Composite createComposite(Shell shell)
{
    Composite comp = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);

    comp.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    comp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        String content = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        content = content.substring(0, Math.round(random.nextFloat() * content.length()));

        Label label = new Label(comp, SWT.RIGHT);
        label.setText(content);
        label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.TOP, false, false));

        Text text = new Text(comp, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));
    }

    return comp;
}

private static void synchronizeFirstColumn(int nrOfColumns, Composite... comps)
{
    if (comps == null || comps.length == 0)
        return;

    int maxWidth = 0;

    for (Composite comp : comps)
    {
        Control[] controls = comp.getChildren();

        for (int i = 0; i < controls.length; i += nrOfColumns)
        {
            int width = controls[i].computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).x;

            if (width > maxWidth)
                maxWidth = width;
        }
    }


    for (Composite comp : comps)
    {
        Control[] controls = comp.getChildren();

        for (int i = 0; i < controls.length; i += nrOfColumns)
        {
            Object data = controls[i].getLayoutData();

            if(data instanceof GridData)
            {
                GridData grid = (GridData) data;

                grid.widthHint = maxWidth;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solves my issue now. Nevertheless I will have to refactor my code at some point not to have to do it this way because this problem occured because in the past someone have not thought too much about the design :/

Comment: @Luke Excellent, glad it worked as a temporary workaround. Good luck with the re-design.